# Как отменить стиль css для элемента

Tags: html, css

Для ссылки определен стиль, как отменить его только для этого элемента?

```
<span class="pr_add"><a href=""> В сумку </a></span>
```

Comment: Переопределите .pr_add a {color: #000; text-decoration: none;}

Comment: в чем вы видите проблему?

Comment: стиль задан общий для все ссылок a href, только для этой ссылке хочу его отменить. ну например как есть атрибут на запрет индексации (к примеру)

Answer (score 2):

Есть свойство all (буквально все свойства), и значение initial которое возвращает все на свои места

```js
$("a").eq(0).css("all", "initial")
```

```css
a {
background:red;
color:white;
padding:50px;
border-radius:50%;
border-bottom:1px solid blue;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Натяжные потолки</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

задай для этой ссылки отдельный класс и примени к нему нужные стили

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите подсветить ссылку указывающую на определенный адрес то можно воспользоваться селектором атрибутов например так:

```
a[href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com"] {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

или так:

```
a[rel="nofollow"] {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```